# What is the purpose of User-Defined Functions under Excel Service Application?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

I have done a lot of research and have concluded that we cannot use VBA present under Excel sheet code in SharePoint.

Today I was reading on excel services in sharepoint. I came across User-defined functions under Excel Service Application settings. I believe that User defined functions refer to the Calculations and VBA (am I wrong on this?).

If true, then, does this bring hope that we can use embedded VBA code present into excel sheet in SharePoint also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user-defined functions in Excel Services are managed code, written with Visual Studio and compiled to a DLL.

See [Understanding Excel Services UDFs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms499792%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Excel Web Apps used to display Excel in the browser on a SharePoint site does not support VBA.